# Init array in C at runtime

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, initialization, runtime

I have not been able to find examples that initialize two-dimension array at run-time.

This is code in perl; can anyone "translate" this code into C?

```
  my @grid;     # grid = 2D array
  my $gr=0;     # rows in grid
  my $gc=0;     # cols in grid
  my @ct;
  if( $ARGV[0] eq '5x5' ) {
    $gr=5; $gc=5;    # grid is all zeroes
    @ct=(2,2,2,2,0);
  }
  if( $ARGV[0] eq '9x9' ) {
    $gr=9; $gc=9;    # grid is all zeroes
    @ct=(2,3,4,2,3,5,3,5,3);
  }
  if( $ARGV[0] eq '6x10' ) {
    $gr=6; $gc=10;
    @grid = (
        [0,8,0,0,0,9,3,5,6,7],
        [6,0,0,5,0,7,0,0,1,0],
        [5,0,2,0,4,1,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1],
        [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [1,5,0,4,2,6,8,0,0,0],
    );
    @ct=(14,41,15,29,26,33,32,27,32,21);
  }
```

Comment: just use ```malloc()``` with pointer. you can then treat it like an array with ```ptr[1]``` for example. if you insist of having an real array at runtime it is not possible, at least at C89. This is because arrays in C are stack - allocated, and you need to specify the size at compile time. If it is fine with you just use ```int foo[5]```

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean. The C initializer executes at runtime if inside a function — and arguably even at file scope.  You can't assign arrays, which limits what you can do with compound literals.  Please clarify what you're hoping to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

“Initialization” is just giving initial values to an object. To do this at run-time, you can do any of the following, among other possibilities:

Initialize in the definition, as shown in the question:

```
int myPoints[3][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9} };
```

Initialize with individual assignments:

```
myPoints[0][0] = 1;
myPoints[0][1] = 2;
myPoints[0][2] = 3;
myPoints[1][0] = 4;
myPoints[1][1] = 5;
myPoints[1][2] = 6;
myPoints[2][0] = 7;
myPoints[2][1] = 8;
myPoints[2][2] = 9;
```

Initialize with code that computes values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    myPoints[i][j] = 3*i + j + 1;
```

Copy from a compound literal:

```
memcpy(myPoints, (const int [3][3]) { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9} }, sizeof myPoints);
```

In the first case (initializing with the definition), if `myPoints` is a static object, the compiler is likely to store the values in the object file, to be loaded as part of program loading. If `myPoints` is an automatic object, it is likely to generate instructions to store values for the array. Technically, the C standard permits the compiler to do either of these for any of the examples above. Which is used is a matter of optimization and compiler implementation. So the distinction of initializing at “run-time” is largely irrelevant unless performance issues are important.

Comment: My question has been modified to clarify my request; "myPoints" has been removed.